# Does Spring MVC support extension-less URLs?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, tomcat, spring-mvc

Does Spring MVC support extension-less URLs like asp.net MVC does?

I am just getting started with Spring MVC.

Or maybe has nothing to do with Spring MVC but Tomcat?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Yes, it does.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping)

If you are using annotations, you annotate your controller methods or classes with something like:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
```

Which will respond to `/hello` when you map the dispatcher servlet like so:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not true. "/hello" in this case is just part of URL. Extension is defined in /WEB-INF/web.xml - something like <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>

Comment: @jirka.pinkas: web.xml can handle **any** urls. If you want to get all urls (including those without extension) to be caught by Spring, use this string: `<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>` in your web.xml. `dispatcher` here is Spring's `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: @ffriend thanks, I didn't know, that "/" mapping would work. I tested it and it works!

Comment: @jirka: Edited for clarity ;-)

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler: Now it's perfect ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must set this in your /WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

(assuming your DispatcherServlet is named "dispatcher").