# How to remove the .action/.html/(.any) suffix extension in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflow

Is there any way to remove `.action/.html/(.any)` extension in Spring MVC like [Struts2](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/how-to-remove-the-action-suffix-extension-in-struts-2/).

I'm looking for a clean URL in my address bar.

Like: `http://localhost:8080/SpringProject/Dashboard`
Rather than: `http://localhost:8080/SpringProject/Dashboard.html`

**Solution That I have found :**

Added two line in my spring-servlet.xml file

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

and modify my web.xml

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

that's all

I also post this answer in my blog [javalink2me.blogspot](http://javalink2me.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-remove-any-suffix-extension-in.html)

Comment: What do you mean remove it? Where?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I update my question. Please notice

Comment: Change your `@RequestMapping` values from `/something.html` to `/something`.

Comment: Since I am writing in web.xml spring <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>. how it take other/none extension.
@SotiriosDelimanolis I am totally new to this technology. May be I am wrong. Please suggest

Comment: We'd have to see more of your request handlers. Instead of extension mapping, you could use path matching for your Servlet url-pattern.

Comment: What about `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`? Possible duplicate: [Does Spring MVC support extension-less URLs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178549)

Comment: hello @ADTC I follow your link whose really work for me now I got another problem 
i.e : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringProject/css/styles.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Comment: my css,javascript and images are not loaded.. please help

Comment: I apologize I'm unable to help you further. I suggest you to post a new question with more details `=)`

Comment: See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-default-servlet-handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for @Controller and @RequestMapping is provided by Spring by default. However, by enabling mvc:annotation-driven you get support for processing the requests that are mapped to annotated controller methods, such as declarative validation, formatting and conversion service.

**In servlet-config.xml**

`<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />`

**In WEB.xml**

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>home</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to configure your controller with the path you want.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Inject
    private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping("/mypath")
    public String showPathWithouteExtension(Model model) {

        return "myjspfile";
    }

}
```

With a controller like this, you just need to call.

> http://server:port/myapp/mypath

and boom, no extension. :)