# URL Redirect in Servlet after form

Tags: java, servlets

In my Java web app I have a unique Front Controller which maps all the requests, and various controllers that execute the logic and return a string representing the next page the user is forwarded to.

This works, but when I submit a form with post method, the form action gets appended to the URL in the address bar. For example, if the login method in LoginController returns false (so that nextPage="/index.jsp"), it correctly redirects to that page, but in the address bar I'll have /MyAPP/app/home.jsp anyway. Is there a way to avoid this?

I took a look to the Post/Redirect/Get pattern, but I'd like to figure out how can I implement this without aggressively changing the structure.

```
@WebServlet("/app/*")
public class FrontController extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Map<String, Controller> controllers = new HashMap<String, Controller>();

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String pathInfo = req.getPathInfo();
        String controllerName = pathInfo.substring(pathInfo.lastIndexOf('/'));
        Controller c = controllers.get(controllerName);
        String resource = c.action(req, resp);
        req.getRequestDispatcher(resource).forward(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        controllers.put("/index.jsp", new IndexController());
        controllers.put("/home.jsp", new LoginController());
    }
}


public class LoginController implements Controller {

    private static final String USERNAME_PARAM = "username";
    private static final String PASSWORD_PARAM = "password";
    private static final String USERBEAN_ATTR = "userBean";

    public String action(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String username = request.getParameter(USERNAME_PARAM);
        String password = request.getParameter(PASSWORD_PARAM);
        boolean result = false;
        UserBean userBean = (UserBean)request.getSession().getAttribute(USERBEAN_ATTR);

        userBean.setUsername(username);
        userBean.setPassword(password);

        if (!username.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty())
            result = userBean.doLogin();

        String nextPage = result ? "/home.jsp" : "/index.jsp";

        if (!result)
            request.setAttribute("error", "Login Error");

        return nextPage;
    }
}

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>

    <form
        action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/app/home.jsp"
        method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"> <br>
        Password: <input type="text" name="password"> <br> <input
            type="submit" value="Log In" />
    </form>
    <p>${error}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not really. You could have a 'jump' jsp that mimics the "Post/Redirect/Get pattern" where the view jsp is an intermediate jsp that will 'on load' on the browser request the actual jsp. For that reason, it could even be a html page. Not directly related, both these techniques will save you from user refreshes that causes double submit.

Comment: Are you talking about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178549/does-spring-mvc-support-extension-less-urls?